# Return error if no parameter in function

Tags: javascript

What are some good practices for returning errors from a function that requires parameters are not executed within the function?

```
function someFunction(hello, world) {
  if (!hello) {
    console.error("missing first parameter")
  } else if (!world) {
    console.error("missing second parameter")
  } else if (!hello && !world) {
    console.error("missing both parameters")
  }
}

someFunction("hola");
```

Comment: throw new Error('missing param')

Comment: In your example it will never log the third error, put that as your first condition.

Comment: It was just an example, in a rush for work so I just jotted that down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to detect absent arguments is using typeof( in case undefined being overwritten) and then return accordingly

```
if (typeof hello === 'undefined') {
    console.error("missing first parameter")
    return new Error('missing first parameter')
.....
```

After that you will be able to match the output using `instanceof`

As suggested in comments put the last condition above other conditions and also you cannot miss first argument and get second argument because in that case your second argument will become first argument

```js
function some(hello, world) {
  if (typeof hello === 'undefined' && typeof world === 'undefined') {
    console.error("missing both parameter")
    return new Error("missing both parameter")
  } else if (typeof world === 'undefined') {
    console.error("missing second parameters")
    return new Error("missing second parameter")
  }
}
console.log(some() instanceof Error)
console.log(some('a') instanceof Error)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your code inside a try catch block and throw any exception triggered from your code to the caller.

```
function someFunction(hello, world) {
  try{
   //use any of the arguments
  }catch(err){
   throw new Error('something went wrong');
  }
}
```

another approach that maybe could suit your case is to use default parameters to keep the code safe.

```
function someFunction(hello, world) {
  hello = hello || {};
  world = world || {};
  //hello and world are initialized here in any case
}
```